# Openseadragon simple image

Tags: javascript, html, openseadragon

I am trying to build something, using exist-db and openseadragon:

My file structure can be found in the link.
[click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sGV4H.png)
inside, I have the according files.
For now, I want to use simple images with openseadragon in show.html (located in pages. as all my html-files are stored in that folder.)

my show.html looks like this:

```
<div class="content-container">
<div class="column">blablabla</div>
<div class="column" id="dragon-container">
<div id="seadragon-viewer" style="height:600px; width:100%; position:right;"/>
</div>
```

var viewer = OpenSeadragon({
          id: "seadragon-viewer",
          tpye: "image",
          url: "/data/images/Page0001.JPG"
        });

```
    </div>
```

[This](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cdvQ2.png) is what I get. An empty openseadragon-div with the navigation toggle.

I first thought I messed up the URL and added "../" (or any other location) to it, but to no avail. 
Can anyone point me in the right direction?

After I got Page0001.JPG to display, I'll make a Sequence out of the 18 pictures that I have (and sync the openseadragon-viewer to the divs containing the accompanying text)

This is just a first step, I think I'll be going for DZIs afterwards. However, I have only crappy fotos for now and I'll have to take better ones, so why not make a "concept" before I add the final pictures (+ I want to learn something!)

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You need to put the image specification in your `tileSources` property, like so:

```
var viewer = OpenSeadragon({ 
  id: "seadragon-viewer", 
  tileSources: {
    type: "image", 
    url: "/data/images/Page0001.JPG" 
  }
});
```